# Why am I missing 'notification' features on my entityforms?

Tags: 7, emails, entities

A coworker installed entityforms on a staging site and it delivers email notifications nicely.  I am trying to replicate the process on the production site, but I am missing all the features/UI related to email notifications.

Below you can see I'm missing access/submission/validation options.  I am also missing the 'Notifications' tab that should show up on the entityform 'edit' page.

**Staging server**
[image]

**Production server**
[image]

- I have the rules module and other dependencies (auto-installed with drush)
- I have Entityforms Notifications enabled
- I have Rules UI enabled

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because... I have different versions of Entityforms on staging and production.  In the more recent version (7.x-2.0-beta2), they just moved things around.

You can get to the notification rules now by going to `Structure > Entityform Types > [form]` and clicking the `Rules` tab.

[image]

Comment: Also people should know that Entityform Notifications requires Entity Rules now.